# Insert New Row (register) , in th mean time insert "Auto Increment ID" into another column

Tags: php, mysqli

Insert New Row (register) , in the meantime insert "Auto Increment ID" into another column

I have no idea how to do this (able to do normal registration)

```
$query = "insert into usertable (name,email,password) values('$username','$email','$password')";
```

In database table:

```
ID(AI)   name        email            password     nameID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        test1       test1@gmail.com    1234       NULL (what I want: 1)    
2        test2       test2@gmail.com    1234       NULL (what I want: 2)
3        test3       test3@gmail.com    1234       NULL (what I want: 3)
```

Comment: what you have tried till now?

Comment: Why would you need two identical columns ? Seems a waste of space. DO you maybe have another problem you want to solve with this action?

Comment: Why need two column for the same data? Why not just rename `ID` to `nameID` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you could do with last inserted id [`mysqli_insert_id($conn)`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)

```
$query = "insert into usertable (name,email,password) values('$username','$email','$password')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) { //  after you insert executed successfully
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); //your last inserted auto increment value
            //update with same row another column
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE usertable SET nameID='$last_id' WHERE ID='$last_id'");
           }
```